# Scraping webpage generated by javascript

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, screen-scraping

I have a problem getting javascript content into HTML to use it for scripting. I used multiple methods as phantomjs or python QT library and they all get most of the content in nicely but the problem is that there are javascript buttons inside the page like this:

[Pls see screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hYVH.png)

Now when I load this page from a script these buttons won't default to any value so I am getting back 0 for all SELL/NEUTRAL/BUY values below. Is there a way to set these values when you load the page from a script?

Example page with all the values is: https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/NEBLBTC/technicals/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show us some code of what you tried and what is not working so that someone can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to achieve this with scrapy or with derivation of `cURL` or `urrlib` I am afraid that you can't do this. Python has another external packages such selenium that allow you to interact with the javascript of the page, but the problem with selenium is too slow, if you want something similar to scrapy you could check how the site works (as i can see it works through ajax or websockets) and fetch the info that you want through `urllib`, like you would do with an API.

Please let me know if you understand me or i misunderstood your question

Answer (score 0):

I used seleneum which was perfect for this job, it is indeed slow but fits my purpose. I also used the seleneum firefox plugin to generate the python script as it was very challenging to find where exactly in the code as the button I had to press.